# How to get excel Footer text in VB.Net with GetOleDbSchemaTable metode

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Function GetExcelFooter(ByVal fileName As String) As String
    Dim strconn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=" & fileName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;';Jet OLEDB:Database Password=indonesia"
    Dim konn As New OleDbConnection(strconn)
    GetExcelFooter = ""
    konn.Open()

    Dim dtSheets As DataTable = konn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables_Info, Nothing)
    ' Dim listSheet As New List(Of String)
    Dim drSheet As DataRow

    For Each drSheet In dtSheets.Rows
        GetExcelFooter = drSheet("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
    Next


    konn.Close()

End Function
```

Comment: You could help us to help you by adding some information in your question text. Particularly, what you are trying to achieve and the expected result?

Comment: How to get an excel worksheet footer with a method other than CreateObject ("Excel.Application").
I don't want to use the Microsoft Excel Object Library. I want to run my application on a PC without MS. Excel installed.
Thank you for your answer.